# Getting verbose information from libcurl to a file

Tags: c++, qt, curl, libcurl

I am trying to develop a QT Application in C/C++ which uses libcurl. Simply, i want to save VERBOSE data to a file. In libcurl API documentation, it is said that (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html)

> The verbose information will be sent to stderr, or the stream set with CURLOPT_STDERR.

So, VERBOSE information will be at stderr. And after i followed the link for CURLOPT_STDERR (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_STDERR.html) which tells,

> Pass a FILE * as parameter. Tell libcurl to use this stream instead of stderr when showing the progress meter and displaying CURLOPT_VERBOSE data.

At the CURLOPT_STDERR link, there exists a code sample. I've tried it on my own application as:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
FILE *filep = fopen("dump.txt", "wb");
if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, filep);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);


if (CURLE_OK != res) {      
    fprintf(stderr, "curl told us %d\n", res);
}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
fclose(filep);
```

However, verbose information isn't shown at command line and the file which is created for the verbose information is empty. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Does the correct output show up on stderr? (ie-console)

Comment: @johnelemans verbose information does not show up on console with this code.

Comment: The code looks okay. Confirm that there is output to stderr without the re-direct and if not, debug that first.

Comment: @johnelemans if i comment out the line
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, filep);
it prints the verbose information to console. However, i want that information saved in the file. But file is empty in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The following example works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURLcode ret;
  CURL *hnd;
  FILE* logfile;

  logfile = fopen("dump.txt", "wb");

  hnd = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.org");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_STDERR, logfile);

  ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

  curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
  fclose(logfile);

  return (int)ret;
}
```

Comment: Your example does not work for me. Actually, i copied this example and used, however log file is still empty.

Comment: What OS, compiler and curl version are you using ? I was using Fedora 24, GCC 6.1 and curl 7.47.

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit, VS 2015 Default Compiler and curl 7.50.0

Comment: It worked perfectly for me (Rocky linux 9), I found an error I was looking for for days!
Thank you!